# Android Emulator crashes on Api higher than 28

Tags: android, windows, android-emulator, emulation, android-virtual-device

I used the Android Emulator with API 28 for some month but now was the time to update the API level. So i switched my virtual devices to API 29 and 30, and they stopped working. If i start them, they crash within 3 seconds without any error or message. If I downgrade to API 28, they run as expected.

I am using those Devices:
- Pixel 3
- Pixel C
- Pixel XL

My OS is Windows 10.0.18362

Comment: What is the output of the log window?

Comment: I am having the same problem. There is nothing I haven't tried. The interesting thing is that there are no errors. There is no memory leak. Only the application is closing.

Comment: There is no problem under API 29.